# Can we use cassandra-driver-core-3.11.2.jar to connect to DSE 6.8?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, dse

I'm new to cassandra.Our application uses cassandra-driver-core-3.1 to connect to Apache Cassandra.We've a requirement to connect to DSE 6.8.Can we use cassandra-driver-core-3.11.2 classes to connect to DSE6.8 instead of using DSE specific classes?

```
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
LinkedList<InetSocketAddress> localLinkedList = new LinkedList<InetSocketAddress>();
String host = "****";
String port = "9042";
localLinkedList.add(new InetSocketAddress(host, Integer.valueOf(port)));
builder.addContactPointsWithPorts(localLinkedList);
Session session = builder.build().connect("people");
```

Comment: If you get an error, I have a feeling that it will be a "protocol error."  If so, try forcing a CQL protocol version of 4.

Comment: Can you confirm what version of Java driver that you're using? If you're using the unified java driver (https://github.com/datastax/java-driver), why not just use 4.14.1 (or whatever is newest in 4.x) since it still works with DSE 6.8?